# installing a python package from tar.gz

Tags: python, ubuntu, package, tar

I need to use the cvxopt package for python 3. I run Ubuntu.

So I downloaded cvxopt-1.1.9.tar.gz and extracted the content (a single folder called cvxopt-1.1.9) into a folder
/home/myname/TargetFolder/
manually, not via the command window.

1. When I run the sequence .configure, then make and then sudo make install, none of them works.
2. There is a setup.py file in /home/myname/TargetFolder/cvxopt-1.1.9/. When I go to that directory in the command window and type python setup.py install, then I get the following error message:

> error: can't create or remove files in install directory
>
> The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
>   installation directory:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/test-easy-install-6110.write-test'
```

> The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
>   the distutils default setting) was:

```
/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
```

> Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
>   installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
>   as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
>   access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
>   directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
>   variable.
>
> For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
>   documentation at:

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

That link doesn't exist anymore.

3. So I follow the advice on http://cvxopt.org/install/ . Apart from the "python setup.py install" command, which didn't work for me, I tried the second thing on their list. Namely "pip install cvxopt"
   This gave:

> Collecting cvxopt
>    Downloading cvxopt-1.1.9.tar.gz (1.9MB)
>      100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.9MB 271kB/s 
>   Building wheels for collected packages: cvxopt
>    Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cvxopt
>    Complete output from command /home/myname/anaconda3/bin/python3 -c >"import setuptools;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-r3o_hfm6/cvxopt/setup.py';>exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpv0ura7txpip-wheel-:
>
> running bdist_wheel
>    running a lot of other stuff

and then

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
>    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
>    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---
>
> Failed building wheel for cvxopt
>   Failed to build cvxopt

and then

> Installing collected packages: cvxopt
>     Running setup.py install for cvxopt
>       Complete output from command /home/myname/anaconda3/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-r3o_hfm6/cvxopt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1f4yz1xm-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       UPDATING build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/cvxopt/_version.py
>       set build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/cvxopt/_version.py to '1.1.9'
>       running build_ext
>       building 'base' extension

and then after some more lines it says:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
>       /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---
>
> Command "/home/myname/anaconda3/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-r3o_hfm6/cvxopt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1f4yz1xm-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-r3o_hfm6/cvxopt
>   You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

If I understood more about Linux and Python I could have focused on the important things and shortened the post a little. But since I know nothing, I post everything I did to maximize the possibility of helpful responses.

Maybe I just don't understand how python works. When I include a package I do this with the

`import package`

command. But `import cvxopt` doesn't work. So if I understood what it is exactly doing, then maybe I could use logic to give her or him that cvxopt package, where it is looking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running Ubuntu, simply run `sudo apt-get install python-cvxopt`

I can install it this way on 16.04. Not sure what version you are running.

It does look like the compiler (gcc) is complaining because you are missing dependencies (blas). Installing via the package manager should solve your issues.

Comment: When I use the package manager, which is a great idea (Thanks!!) then I get the following message:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

python-cvxopt: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.23-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
               Depends: libglpk36 (>= 4.51) but 4.57-1build3 is to be installed
               Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.7.11-1 is to be installed

Comment: So did it install or not? If it installed, and has unmet dependencies you can use ```sudo apt-get install -f``` to fix that. You might also want to update (I left this off earlier since its kind of implied, but you indicated you're a linux novice) ```sudo apt-get update``` before you do any of the commands.

Comment: no, it didn't install. 
I updated with apt-get update. then I tried sudo apt-get install -f and 
and again sudo apt-get install python-cvxopt or various combinations of the two. But I got:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-cvxopt : Depends: libgsl2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: This is sooooo time consuming. And sooo difficult. All these names and one really requires a PhD in this to get the head around it. Anyways, I think that I have a problem with the PythonPath. Because it seems that python-cvxopt has been successfully installed. But I don't know the current path and I don't know if its wise to change it and how to change it. And whether I should manually move the installed package into that path and how to do that. I looked on other threads that explain how to spit out the python path, but none of them works for me. Why is all this such a pain...

Comment: I'll just write my own convex optimization algorithm. Probably won't be that fast, but I just have no more time left for this package business.

Comment: it sounds like you've done something at some point that left your packages in a bad state. You might just trying installing blas and see if you can build the package from source again. (the package is called libblas-dev)

Comment: cheers Bryant. I'll tick off your answer as accepted. A friend of mine recommended a virtual environment or something. I'll also look into that. Because I have a python 2.7 and a python 3.5 version on my computer, so I think there is a conflict most likely.

Comment: You can also use something like conda to manage multiple versions of python.